# Can “itch” be a transitive verb, i.e., can an itch be itched?

Tags: verbs, transitive-verbs

Can *itch* be used as a transitive verb? In other words, can you *itch an itch* as you would *scratch an itch*? Dictionaries differ, with the bigger hitters saying no. Are they bearing the proper standard or just playing it conservative?

Comment: As in, "Mummy (*or* Mommy *if you like*), my nose is itching me!"

Comment: Ogden Nash, *[Taboo to Boot](http://rss.boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/30729/item/644772#item644772)* - One bliss for which /
There is no match /
Is when you itch /
To up and scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to explain what you mean by "proper standard" — but, no, what the "bigger hitters" (again, what are these?) are doing is waiting until a usage is far-reaching enough for them to bother to document it. I guess that's what you'd call playing it conservative.

That said, what one does to an itch is scratch it. Something can *itch* (intransitive) all by itself, or be *itchy*, but *itching* an itch feels like a bizarre usage to me. I'd be curious to know what dictionaries endorse that use.

NOAD, for example, lists only an intransitive form:

> **itch** verb [intrans.] be the site of or cause an itch : *the bite itched like crazy*.

**Addendum** I answered this nine years ago, but since then I've recognized that this usage does in fact exist, though still without apparent documentation in the usual sources. See [this new question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/530262/how-did-itch-come-to-be-used-to-mean-scratch-as-in-i-had-to-itch-my-leg) on EL&U.

Comment: see my (previous) answer, for both your questions :)

Comment: Here's three online dictionaries that allow _itch_ as a synonym for _scratch_: [yourdictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/itch), [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/itch), and [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/itch). (And by "bigger hitters" I meant NOAD and Merriam-Webster.)

Comment: @Callithumpian AHD, a big hitter, licenses the usage. Collins, a big hitter, lists it but with the caveat 'non-standard'. Random House Kernerman Webster's, a big hitter, lists it, with the caveat 'informal'.  'dictionary.com' is a disingenuous umbrella label here. _And I'll wager OED includes it._

Answer (score 3):

Well, even if you use *itch* as a transitive verb, as the *[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/itch)* allows, it means “to cause to itch” or “to vex, to irritate”. So, you don't *itch an itch* as you would *scratch it*: *itch*, in that sense, is not synonymous with *scratch*.

Comment: So would you say the sources I listed in my comment under Robusto's answer are incorrect to allow _itch_ as an informal synonym for _scratch_?

Comment: I would say they are being descriptivist, reflecting the changing usage, rather than being prescriptivist, and describing the "correct" way to use the word(s).  (Personally I find "itch" as a synonym for "scratch" to be pointless and irritating, and I happily correct people when I hear them using "itch" 'incorrectly'.)